# How can I access an array declared in an HTML hidden input from a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have declared an array in a hidden input in my HTML form. Now I want to access that array in a Javascript function. For this, I have written the following code:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sq[]" ></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="a" ></input>
</form>
```

And in the Javascript function:

```
function myfunction()
{
  document.form1.a.value=i; // Here, I can access the variable 'a'
                            // (since a is not in the form of array)
  var i;
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  {
    document.form1.sq[i].value=i; // Here, I am not able to access array named sq[].
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking in terms of PHP instead of JavaScript.

Comment: This is not how javascript works. You have not declared an array and you can't access DOM elements like that.

Comment: @j08691 , i want to use this function to modify the same web page by taking the another values (at the place of i) from different form of the same page. i don't want to use this in terms of php.

Comment: @MattR, suggest me the method to access DOM element. but one thing i want to specify here that it is working correctly in the simple case i.e. when i am trying to access "a" in the above question , it works correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naming a hidden input `sq[]` doesn't change it into an array. It's still just a text field essentially. You will need to access the field and parse the value as a comma-separated list (or JSON or whatever format you choose).

Assuming you have a form like so:

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="sq[]" value="a,b,c,d" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sqjson[]" value='["e","f","g","h"]' />
</form>
```

You can access the values using split *<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)</sup>*:

```
var arr = document.form1['sq[]'].value.split(',');
for (var ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
    console.log(arr[ii]);
}
```

Or using JSON.parse *<sup>[[MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)</sup>*, which would make more complex objects easier to store in a hidden field:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(document.form1['sqjson[]'].value);
for (var ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii++) {
    console.log(arr[ii]);
}
```

[Click here for a working version of this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5v0hybpL/)

Answer (score 3):

You can store `sq` array in JSON format in the hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="sq" value="[]" ></input>
```

Then using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` you can deserialize from string value to memory object, add/remove values in the array, then storing it back to the hidden field.

```
var $sq = JSON.parse($("#sq").val());
...
$("#sq").val(JSON.stringify($sq);
```

Without JQuery:

```
var hf = document.getElementById("sq");
var sq = JSON.parse(hf.value);
...
hf.value = JSON.stringify(sq);
```

Then you can pass `sq` as parameter to functions where needed. Or store it in global variable.

Comment: This solution requires jQuery, which the OP does not appear to be using.

Comment: @Francois B. i want to first initialize the array and than use this to modify the webpage(by using document.getElementById("id_of_div").innerHTML=sq[i]) in another function.